# Apache reverse proxy to Node - Connection refused: AH00957

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, node.js

I am trying to get a brand new cloud based server working with a default version of 20.04 server ubuntu working with apache and node. The node server appears to be running without issues reporting 4006 port is open. However I believe my apache config is not. The request will hang for a very very long time. No errors are displayed in the node terminal.

I have confirmed that everything is correct on the node side with the following command which returns the full json object from apache:

```
// Works as expected and returns results correctly 
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST <json>'  -H "Host: https://<https_url>.com" http://127.0.0.1:4006/graphql
```

### Request error after some time

```
502 proxy error
```

### Apache Error Log

```
[Sun Oct 17 20:58:56.608793 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 1596878] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to [::1]:4006 (localhost) failed
[Sun Oct 17 20:58:56.608909 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1596878] [client 207.46.13.93:27392] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

### vhost

```
<VirtualHost <Server Ip Address>:80>
    ServerName api.aDomain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://api.aDomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost <Server Ip Address>:443>
        ServerName api.aDomain.com

        ProxyRequests on
        LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
        LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:4006/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4006/
    

        #certificates SSL
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/api.aDomain.com/apimini.ca
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/api.aDomain.com/apimini.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/api.aDomain.com/apimini.key

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_api.aDomain.com.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_api.aDomain.com.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### terminal output

```
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node -r dotenv/config --inspect=9229 index.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/c1fcf271-aea8-47ff-910e-fe5a91fce6d2
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
 Server ready at http://localhost:4006
```

### Node server

```
import cors from 'cors'

import scrape from './src/api/routes/scrape'

const express = require('express')
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express')
const { postgraphile } = require('postgraphile')
const ConnectionFilterPlugin = require('postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter')

const dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST
const dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT
const dbName = process.env.DB_NAME
const dbUser = process.env.DB_USER
const dbPwd = process.env.DB_PWD
const dbUrl = dbPwd
  ? `postgres://${dbUser}:${dbPwd}@${dbHost}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`
  : `postgres://${dbHost}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}

async function main() {
  // Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
  const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
      hello: String
    }
  `

  // Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
  const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      hello: () => 'Hello world!',
    },
  }

  const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })

  const app = express()
  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
  app.use(
    postgraphile(process.env.DATABASE_URL || dbUrl, 'public', {
      appendPlugins: [ConnectionFilterPlugin],
      watchPg: true,
      graphiql: true,
      enhanceGraphiql: true,
    })
  )
  server.applyMiddleware({ app })

  //Scraping Tools
  scrape(app)

  const port = 4006
  await app.listen({ port })
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}`)
}

main().catch(e => {
  console.error(e)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: Apache tries to connect via IPv6, use 127.0.0.1 instead localhost or -what will be better, bind your app to ipv4 AND ipv6 :-) (  `attempt to connect to [::1]:4006 (localhost) failed` )

Comment: Another minor issue (probably not related): Here `-H "Host: https://<https_url>.com"` you should not specify `https://`, just `-H "Host: domain.com"` is correct one.

Comment: I'm actually using the IP of the server. I should have made that more clear :D I will update